# How to get blockchain block load from blockfrost?

Tags: api, blockfrost

I'm currently going through Blockfrost documentation and trying to figure out if there is a way to fetch block load for each day.

Seems like they don't have such option, in that case: Is there a way to calculate block load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Blockfrost endpoint retrieves this information.

As per [this tweet](https://twitter.com/InputOutputHK/status/1518596128056520707), the current size of blocks is 88KB.

So, you can calculate the % of block load for each block this way:

```
( cardano_node_metrics_blockfetchclient_blocksize / (88 * 1024) ) * 100
```

`cardano_node_metrics_blockfetchclient_blocksize` is a metric exposed by [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) in the `cardano-node`. You can query it using [Grafana](https://grafana.com/). Unfortunately, you will need to run your own node for this.

This is a very useful link on how to setup the Grafana Dashboard: https://developers.cardano.org/docs/stake-pool-course/handbook/grafana-dashboard-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you! However, there is no APIs that will not require to run node? I assume I just need to fetch size of the block and then make calculations myself

Comment: The problem is that, in order to fetch the size of the block (cardano_node_metrics_blockfetchclient_blocksize), you need to use Grafana. And Grafana is a tool made to monitor your own node: you can't plug it to an API.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking for a way without running a node, example using Koios (am sure blockfrost offers similar endpoints too):

1. Max size of block from current protocol can be found using [epoch_params](https://api.koios.rest/#get-/epoch_params)
2. I am not sure if I fully understand the term `block load` , but I assume you mean average size of blocks for a specific time range. You can get a filtered list of size and time using [blocks](https://api.koios.rest/#get-/blocks) endpoint, the list is - ofcourse - paginated, which you can find an average of.
   Sample: [here](https://api.koios.rest/api/v0/blocks?select=block_size&block_time=gt.2022-06-07T19:00:00)